# Packages for real-time tracking (using static stereo cameras) of a small ball/ball-like marker on Drone

Tags: ros, tracking, realtime, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update**: By marker I mean something like the ball-like structures as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHpy_Ou0YFo). These are being used by expensive motion capture cameras
like Optitrack.

**I do not wish to purchase the Vicon camera**, but build something similar (probably a much crappy version, but something that works).

========

Hi,

Are there any packages for **real-time tracking (only 2D position in image needed)** of a ball/*ball-like* marker (*on a drone*) in ROS ?
I have seen [hueblob](https://github.com/laas/hueblob) but unable to launch it.

Has anyone used hueblob or other packages (for the above purpose) in ROS ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288942/packages-for-real-time-tracking-(using-static-stereo-cameras)-of-a-small-ball/ball-like-marker-on-drone./) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[**ball**/marker in ROS ?]

Ball tracking is widely used in humanoid robot football game like [ROBOCUP](http://www.robocup.org/), [FIRA](http://www.firaworldcup.org/).

Check out the video (from 57sec) below. I also attach the related source code, so please refer to it if necessary. :)

- https://youtu.be/HqZa0LVjk2Y?t=57s
- https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/ROBOTIS-OP3-Demo/tree/master/op3_ball_detector

[ball/**marker** in ROS ?]

If you are looking for a marker-based package, I would recommend the [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) package. It is widely used as an AR tag tracking library in the ROS community.

- http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar

The link below introduces the source code for one example video using the ar_track_alvar package. I think it is good to refer to this.

- https://discourse.ros.org/t/tb3-turtlebot3-automatic-parking-under-ar-detection/4476
- https://youtu.be/dvpWdrD3bVs
- https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_applications/tree/develop/turtlebot3_automatic_parking_vision

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-18**:
Hi,

Thanks for pointing those out, unfortunately I am already aware of alvar-track but as I mentioned in the question, I am looking for tracking ***markers on the drone.*** I have updated the question with a precise meaning of marker.

Also, I think the github link for the ball-tracking is broken.

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2018-04-18**:
Hi again,
I modified the link for ball-tracking.
If your purpose is to recognize the position and orientation by attaching a marker to the drones indoors, I would recommend the Vicon described in the link below.

- http://wiki.ros.org/vicon_mocap

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-18**:
I dont think I understand you. Don't I need to purchase Vicon cameras for that ? I am trying to make my own  motion cap with cheap cameras ...

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2018-04-18**:
Yes, you're right. :)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-04-18**:
The [rpg_monocular_pose_estimator](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_monocular_pose_estimator) package requires a set of LEDs with known transforms between them, but it works well. Their [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ui3MoOxcPQ) shows tracking a quadrotor.

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2018-04-18**:
@jarvisschultz, It is good information. :)
@malharjajoo, The reason I answer above is that your question title was "Packages for real-time tracking a small ball / marker in ROS". It has been modified now ...

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-18**:
Yes, apologies for that. was incomplete on my behalf. I think what @jarvisschultz has given may be what I need. An interesting point to note about infrared: it may not work in sunlight :). Also, not sure upto what distance it can track , but Ill have a look .. thanks @jarvisschultz and @Pyo

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2018-04-18**:
Another alternative method is to use the Kinect and markers proposed by CrazyFlie Team. Well ... The team does provide some ROS packages, but some seem to be incomplete because they work on Windows for Kinect2. You can think it as a reference only. I leave the link below for you.

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2018-04-18**:\

- https://wiki.bitcraze.io/doc:crazyflie:visio
- http://wiki.ros.org/crazyflie
- https://github.com/whoenig/crazyflie_ros

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The visp_tracker package might work ok and it only requires a webcam. If the ball/marker-thing will be far from the camera, I don't think it will work well.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1